# Performance Issue of a Join in Xquery

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, xquery-3.0

I have a strange performance issue while performing joins at multiple levels, say I have a huge xml  out of which I need to perform joins(on the records inside that huge xml, approx few thousands) and define 4 hierarchy levels (Parent/Child relatioships). However, joins at three levels(one join at each level) work fine but join at 4th level takes couple of hours to complete. Any inputs and guidance is much appreciated. Thanks.
***Eg: Source XML***

```
<items>
<item>
<level>1</level>
<parentref></parentref>
<parentitem></parentitem>
<itemno>123</itemno>
<itemname>Laptop</itemname>
</item>
<item>
<level>2</level>
<parentref>1</parentref>
<parentitem>123</parentitem>
<itemno>111</itemno>
<itemname>Keyboard</itemname>
</item>
<item>
<level>2</level>
<parentref>1</parentref>
<parentitem>123</parentitem>
<itemno>112</itemno>
<itemname>Mouse</itemname>
</item>
<item>
<level>3</level>
<parentref>2</parentref>
<parentitem>112</parentitem>
<itemno>112-1</itemno>
<itemname>Fiber Mouse</itemname>
</item>
<item>
<level>4</level>
<parentref>3</parentref>
<parentitem>112-1</parentitem>
<itemno>112-2</itemno>
<itemname>Mouse Pad and USB</itemname>
</item>
</items>
```

***Expected Output:***

```
<items>
<item>
<itemno>123</itemno>
<itemname>Laptop</itemname> -- Level 1 ( Top level always be one record)
<accessories>               ------------------------------- 
    <itemno>111</itemno>
    <itemname>Keyboard</itemname>  -- Both accessories belong to Level 2 ( can be any number of records)
</accessories>                        one of the accessories has two levels ( can be any number of records) 
<accessories>
    <itemno>112</itemno>
    <itemname>Mouse</itemname>
    <addons>
        <itemno>112-1</itemno>
        <itemname>Fiber Mouse</itemname>
        <moreaddons>                             --- Performance issue is at this level of join
            <itemno>112-2</itemno>                    For 500 addons records, I have almost 5000 moreaddons to match in my source xml.
            <itemname>Mouse Pad and USB</itemname>
        </moreaddons>
    </addons>
</accessories>          
</item>
```

***Sample Join Code that I have used below:***

***Level 1: To get the base item***

```
for $x in input xml
where $x/level=1
```

***Level 2: To get the accosories for a given base item***

```
for $y in $x
for $i in input xml
where $i/level=2
and $y/itemno = $i/parentitem
```

***Level 3: To get the addons for a given accesories***

```
let $p := (for $bv in $i return $bv)
let $lst := (for $id in input xml
             where $ids/level=3 return $id)
return for-each($p,function($p){
if(for-each($lst,function($lst){$p/itemno=$lst/parentitem})=true()
then for $av in input xml
     where $av/level = 3
     and $av/parentitem=$p/itemno
```

***Level 4: To get the moreaddons for a given addons***

```
let $q := (for $cv in $av return $cv)
let $lsts := (for $ids in input xml
             where $ids/level=4 return $ids)
return for-each($q,function($q){
if(for-each($lsts,function($lsts){$q/itemno=$lsts/parentitem})=true()
then for $dv in input xml
     where $dv/level = 4
     and $dv/parentitem=$q/itemno
```

Comment: Are the XQuery snippets incomplete? I don't see any `else` expressions and it seems some function bodies are not closed.

Comment: For a performant join it seems you would want to have an index on `item` for `itemno` and `level`. Whether the processor recognizes that or allows you to declare them depends on the processor you use. Which XQuery processor do you use?

Comment: Performance always depends on the XQuery implementation so the most vital bit of information is to tell us what XQuery product you use.

Comment: Thank you for your valuble inputs @Martin and Michael.  Yes, Intentionllay I removed else part since it doesn't contain any conditions in the code. I use Saxon Xquery Processor that supports both Xquery 1.0 and 3.0 versions. I'll try these code snippets and Thank you both once again.

Comment: In case of Saxon it would be also important to know which edition to use as Saxon EE (and PE?) do have a much better optimizer for queries than HE.

Comment: Do the suggestions made perform better than you initial attempts? If not, perhaps give us some idea about the size of the input XML that takes that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight-forward nested `for..return` approach would look like

```
<items>
{
    for $level1-item in /items/item[level = 1]
    return
        <item>
        {
            $level1-item!(itemno, itemname),
            for $level2-item in /items/item[level = 2 and parentitem = $level1-item/itemno]
            return
                <accessories>
                {
                    $level2-item!(itemno, itemname),
                    for $level3-item in /items/item[level = 3 and parentitem = $level2-item/itemno]
                    return
                        <addons>
                        {
                            $level3-item!(itemno, itemname),
                            for $level4-item in /items/item[level = 4 and parentitem = $level3-item/itemno]
                            return
                                <moreaddons>
                                {
                                    $level4-item!(itemno, itemname)
                                }
                                </moreaddons>
                        }
                        </addons>
                }
                </accessories>
        }
        </item>
}
</items>
```

In the end the nesting asks for a function taking a level:

```
declare variable $names as xs:string* external := ('item', 'acessories', 'addons', 'moreaddons');

declare function local:nest($root as document-node()) as element()*
{
    let $level := 1
    for $item in $root/items/item[level = $level]
    return 
        element { $names[$level] } {
           $item/itemno,
           $item/itemname,
           local:nest($root, $item, $level + 1)
        }
};

declare function local:nest($root as document-node(), $parent as element(item), $level as xs:integer) as element()*
{
    for $item in $root/items/item[level = $level and parentitem = $parent/itemno]
    return
        element { $names[$level] } {
           $item/itemno,
           $item/itemname,
           local:nest($root, $item, $level + 1)
        }
};

<items>
{
    local:nest(/)

}
</items>
```

Comment: Hi @Martin - Sorry about taking time on responding , the straigt-forward for... return approach worked far more better than my code and considerably reduced from 4-5hrs to 20-30 mins,however I still feel I have some more room for improvements like as you mentioned adding indexes to it. The size of the xml is almost like more than 600,000 lines. Since, I'm a beginer,could you help me share some tutorial on Xquery/Xpath to get some basic,advanced topics knowledge on or comforatble with queries. Thank you for all your help on guidance.

Comment: @Learner, for learning XQuery 3, I would recommend the latest edition of the book "XQuery: Search Across a Variety of XML Data" by Priscilla Walmsley.

Comment: Thank you somuch @Martin